# Full size download Chartjs canvas on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

This is my Chartjs canvas builds inside the bootstrap and chartjs framework. The problem is I cannot download the full width image while in small screens such as mobile devices.

---- **Bootstrap is a must have**

**--- NOTE: if you make the width of screen in the example small and then click on download the output would be that size and small.**

HTML:

```
<div class="card">

  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title mb-0"> Average </h4>

    <a data-name="avg-chart" id="downloadavg" download="searchtrends-average-position-chart.jpg" href="" class="download">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="white" class=" bi bi-cloud-arrow-down-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 2a5.53 5.53 0 0 0-3.594 1.342c-.766.66-1.321 1.52-1.464 2.383C1.266 6.095 0 7.555 0 9.318 0 11.366 1.708 13 3.781 13h8.906C14.502 13 16 11.57 16 9.773c0-1.636-1.242-2.969-2.834-3.194C12.923 3.999 10.69 2 8 2zm2.354 6.854-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 9.293V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </a>
    <div class="c-chart-wrapper" id="avg-chart_parent">
      <canvas class="chart" id="avg-chart" style="height:300px;width:100%" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("avg-chart"),{"type":"line",
                      "data":{"labels":["2020.11.1","2020.11.2","2020.11.3","2020.11.4","2020.11.5","2020.11.6","2020.11.7","2020.11.7","2020.11.9","2020.11.10","2020.11.11","2020.11.12","2020.11.13","2020.11.14","2020.11.15","2020.11.16","2020.11.17","2020.11.18","2020.11.19","2020.11.20","2020.11.21","2020.11.22","2020.11.23","2020.11.24","2020.11.25","2020.11.26","2020.11.27","2020.11.28","2020.11.29","2020.11.30",],
                      "datasets":[{"label":"Average Position ",
                      "data":["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30",],
                      "fill":false,"borderColor":"rgb(37,154,71)","lineTension":0.1}]}, options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                        reverse: true,
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                distribution: 'series',
                time: {
          tooltipFormat:'MM/DD/YYYY', 
              }
        
                    }]
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            maxWidth: 9999
             
        }
    }});
    
    
        function downloadpng(chartname,chartid){
      var canvas = document.getElementById(chartname);
   var url_base64jp =canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  var a =  document.getElementById(chartid);
  a.href = url_base64jp;
  }
//Download Chart Image
$('.download').on( 'click', function (event) {
  var chartname =  $(this).attr('data-name');
  var chartid =  $(this).attr('id'); 
    downloadpng(chartname,chartid);
 
});
```

I made an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aneeshtan/vu27aew3/49/

As you can see I cannot save the full sized canvas (Chartjs) in small screens and automatically it changes the ratio.

**How can I have the full-sized chartjs canvas to download.**

Comment: Define *"full sized"*.

Comment: like the desktop version showing all the legend labels. minimum size 1200px ?

Comment: Or in other definition showing the full list of legend labels in xAxes .

Comment: So when we make the screen small ( mobile version ) the output would be small but the output should be the full sized version like the desktop output.

Comment: You don't need to explain the problem to me. I just don't understand why you'd want a `1440px` wide image on a `1440px` wide monitor and a `3840px` chart on a 4k monitor. Don't you want a standard size for the chart image when downloading, regardless of what device is used? And if you do, what is that standard? *"Full width"* is what you get now on mobiles. Apparently, you don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a higher resolution snapshot of the chart, you first need to resize it and then wait for it to redraw.

The simplest way to do that is to resize the parent and wait ~ `300ms`.
**Note:** if your chart is more complex (has significantly more data to draw), the resize & redraw might take longer, feel free to increase the timeout interval accordingly - it's `321ms` now.

Because you need to wait for the chart to resize, you can't use the initial click anymore. You need to trigger another one, after the chart has resized.

Lastly, I'm deleting the `href` value after the download. If I don't, any subsequent click on the button will return the first snapshot and, in case the chart is dynamic and you want to be able to snapshot it again without having to refresh the page.

Here's how the code looks like:

```js
function downloadImage(name, id) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const a = $(id)[0];
    a.href = $(name)[0].toDataURL("image/jpg");
    a.click();
  }, 321)
}
$('.download').on('click', function(e) {
  const name = '#' + $(this).data('name');
  const id = '#' + this.id;
  const parent = $(name).parent();
  if (!$(this).attr('href')) {
    parent.css({ width: Math.max(1200, parent.width()) });
    downloadImage(name, id);
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    parent.css({ width: '' });
    setTimeout(() => $(id).attr('href', ''));
  }
});
```

Feel free to change `1200` to whatever `min-width` you want for your chart. Currently, if the displayed chart width is larger than that value, you'll download a bigger image, as you said in comments. I personally find that a bit weird.

If you change your mind, and want the downloaded chart to always have the same size (even when downloaded from larger monitors), replace

```
parent.css({ width: Math.max(1200, parent.width()) });
```

with

```
parent.css({ width: 1920 }); // or whatever fixed chart width you want
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lzdc3bw1/

Comment: Thanks but when clicking on the download button it returns a corrupted image.

Comment: @Farshad. The code in the fiddle was not the one I posted here (which works). For some reason it didn't take the last "Set as base". I've updated the fiddle with what's in the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the time.

Comment: would you tell me how I can add the heading inside the saved image ?

Comment: I can think of at least three methods to achieve that, but answering it here would be against [SO] rules. It's a different question, hence you must ask it separately. Secondly, you have to research the task, try out whatever solutions you find, and only ask if what you tried doesn't work, linking to any documentation stating what you tried should work. If you're looking for coding services for hire, you're on the wrong website. There are other, much better suited places for such requests.

Comment: OK . I found my answer. that would be adding a title as an option to the Chart

Answer (score 0):

Custom dimensions can be applied by creating a new `canvas` element along with a new `canvas context`

```
function downloadpng(chartname, chartid) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(chartname);
  var url_base64jp = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  var a = document.getElementById(chartid);
  
  var resizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var resizedContext = resizedCanvas.getContext("2d");

  resizedCanvas.height = "1080";
  resizedCanvas.width = "1920";
  
  resizedContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
  
  url_base64jp = resizedCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");


  a.href = url_base64jp;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8ywdzr50/1/)

Comment: Download the generated image when the window size is `1920 x 1000` (on a desktop) and then resize the window to a width of under `600px` and download the image again. Do you notice any differences between the two images?

Comment: I do not see any difference. legends xAxes are still not complete.